# Deploy windows form change to client machine without installing it from scratch

Tags: winforms, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Windows Forms project that contains several forms. I have created an installer of the project (setup project) for my users. The problem is whenever I do some change in my form I need to rebuild my project and create a new installer (setup project) for my users. Is there any way to deploy my Win Form change on users machine without installing it from scratch?

Comment: How about using [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Answer (score 2):

That is the only option that Visual Studio setups give you, the RemovePreviousVersions upgrade that consists of the entire rebuilt MSI file.

The usual alternative (when the install is large and the changes are just binary updates) is a Windows Installer patch, a .msp file generated from the difference between old and new MSI files. Visual Studio setup projects don't support patch builds. In any case, the update needs to be Windows Installer-based - the install keeps track of every file installed and replacing them outside of an MSI-based method can result in repairs and other actions requiring access to the original MSI file to re-install the original correct version.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that i found is to split my project into several sub libraries but the main form is in main project and other forms are in separate libraries. So whenever a change is occurred in a form the associative library DLL needs to be modify. So no need to install the setup from scratch.